# Why won't virtualenvwrapper start?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

I have installed virtualenvwrapper and performed the ritual of placing

```
export PATH="/home/jeff/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
```

in .bashrc

If I logout and log back in *workon* gives the error

```
workon: command not found
```

If run

```
source ~./bashrc
```

and call *workon* I get the same error.

It is only by running

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

that I can get virtualenvwrapper to load

What is going on here?

Comment: `pyenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` are two different things. You need to add `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` to your `~./bashrc`

Comment: @phd Thanks. That does it!